# Autofac - Resolve dependencies in WebApi controllers of seperate assemblies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac

I have two projects in a visual studio solution

**ProjectA** - Owin Selfhost Webapi application

**ProjectB** - A Class Library Application (References ProjectA) WebApi controllers are added here

The ProjectB controllers are resolved in ProjectA by Overriding DefaultAssembliesResolver as explained [here](http://www.strathweb.com/2013/08/customizing-controller-discovery-in-asp-net-web-api/).

**ProjectA Code:**

```
//WebApi startup class
public class Startup
{
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
  {

   var config = new HttpConfiguration();
   config.Services.Replace(typeof(IAssembliesResolver), new MyAssemblyResolver());

   var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

   var assemblies = GetExternalControllerAssemblier();
   assemblies.Add(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

   builder.RegisterApiControllers(assemblies.ToArray());

   //Builder reference is passed to external controllers and builder object is updated there
   HandleExtControllerDependency(ref builder, assemblies);

   var container = builder.Build();
   config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
   app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
   app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
  }
}

//I'm using reflection and calling a method in external assembly, to update `builder` object.
private void HandleExtControllerDependency(ref builder, List<Assembly> assemblies)
{
   foreach (component in assemblies)
   {
      var type = assembly.GetType(component+"DependencyHandler");
      IDependencyHandler handler = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IDependencyHandler;
      handler.LoadDependencies(ref builder);
   }
}
```

**Project B Code:**
The `builder` object passed from ProjectA will be updated here.

```
public class DependencyHandler : IDependencyHandler
{
  public void LoadDependencies(ref ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
      builder.RegisterType<Demo>().As<IDemo>();
  }
}
```

**ISSUE:**

I have a controller called DemoController and there is a parameterless constructor. I'm expecting AutoFac to inject the dependency. Seems dependency is not resolved in a controller. Im getting following error:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'DemoController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless
>   public constructor.

**Question**

1) Is my approach to resolve the dependency in external assembly is correct? Is there any better alternative?

2) Should i need this code? `builder.RegisterApiControllers(assemblies.ToArray());`

3) How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autofac provides a simple mechanism to achieve my requirement. I have resolved this by using [AutoFac Assembly Scanning.](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/scanning.html)

1) Create a class and extend with `Module` class and override the Load method. In the Overridden method register the dependency.

```
public class AModule : Module
{
  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.Register(c => new AComponent()).As<AComponent>();
  }
}

public class BModule : Module
{
  protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
  {
    builder.Register(c => new BComponent()).As<BComponent>();
  }
}
```

2) Register the  Modules in Main Application:

```
var assembly = typeof(AComponent).Assembly;
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

// Registers both modules
builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);
```

Note:
Don't forget to register external controllers by calling

```
builder.RegisterApiControllers(<assembly array>);
```

That's it. Happy Coding!